# Javascript - If Statement Woes

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, if-statement

I've been making use of AJAX in my website. AJAX is obviously a 2 way communication.

Here is PHP code which echoes an ID or the word ERROR:

```
$quickCheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pos WHERE type='$type' AND design='$design' AND medium_id='$medium'")or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($quickCheckQuery)==0){
    mysql_query("INSERT pos VALUES(NULL, '$title', '$type', '$design', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$medium')")or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
    echo mysql_insert_id();
}else{
    echo "ERROR";   
}
```

And that does send the word ERROR or the inserted ID back to the client side, as expected.

Here is my "recieve response" in javascript:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
            var newId;
            newId = xmlhttp.responseText;

            if(newId=="ERROR"){
                alert(newId);
                alert("There is an ERROR");
            }else{
                alert(newId);
                alert("Processing Files");
            }

    }
```

Now, what this does is I receive 2 alerts per condition - One side of this could be:

```
Alert 1: ERROR
Alert 2: There is an ERROR

OR 

Alert 1: 5
Alert 2: Processing Files
```

However, What I am actually getting is:

```
Alert 1: ERROR
Alert 2: Processing Files
```

My if statement logic seems simple enough. I just can't kick this problem..

Comment: Try changing your die("ERROR: ") to something else like (die("DB_ERROR") and see if you're still getting the same alerts?

Comment: The logic seems correct, probably `newId` is not *exactly* `"ERROR"`. Maybe there a whites spaces somehow. Try with `newdId.replace(/\s+/g, '') === "ERROR"`.

Comment: Also you could install firebug and check in the console exactly what the ajax call is returning, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I would try adding some extra part to the alert like `alert('If clause'+newId)`... this surely helps

Comment: Okay, I think I've narrowed down my problem to my quickCheckQuery statement. - I'll update!

Comment: No it wasn't that lol. Whitespace wins I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any additional whitespace in your php file. e.g. at the start or end.

Do you close your php file with ?>, if so don't.

You could try removing whitespace from the responseText.

```
newId = xmlhttp.responseText.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried firebug  or ie developer toolbar?
You can then just set a breakpoint in your javascript (press f12 to open, then click on the script tab, find your receive script and click to set the breakpoint at the start of your if - then you can set watches etc), as this all looks correct - but as suggested, there are probably some non-alpha characters before / after error - this will be clear when you set a watch on it.

Otherwise, to debug without this, try alerting this:
alert('"' + newId + '"');
to see if you have trailing spaces

Answer (score 0):

because this might be doing the trick check that

```
die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
```